# How to run grunt from a PHP script?

Tags: php, node.js, gruntjs

I'm trying to execute grunt in a local project from a php script.

I have npm and the grunt cli installed globally.

If I open up terminal and enter:

```
cd /path/to/local/grunt/project/ && grunt
```

Grunt will run successfully and carry out the tasks I've set in the gruntfile.js found in that directory.

However, when I try to shell exec the same thing via a php script

```
var_dump(shell_exec('cd /path/to/local/grunt/project/ && grunt 2>&1'));
```

I get:

```
sh: grunt: command not found
```

I've also tried the direct path to the global CLI:

```
var_dump(shell_exec('/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt 2>&1'));
```

but then I get:

```
env: node: No such file or directory
```

However this runs as expected from terminal.

What's going on here? Why is the grunt command not found when I try to run it via php? How can I shell exec or exec grunt from a php script?

Comment: The PATH variable when using the command line is not the same as what is loaded by the

Comment: I can run others like "/usr/local/bin/optipng" which are found in the same place as grunt. Any suggestions?

Comment: I would think you have a PATH issue.  Try this post here: http://serverfault.com/questions/151328/setting-apache2-path-environment-variable

Answer (score 4):

You need to use absolute paths to node and grunt so execute your command like this

```
var_dump(shell_exec('cd /path/to/local/grunt/project/ && /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/grunt 2>&1'));
```